# Como omitir os chunks no RMarkdown?

Tags: r, rmarkdown

Esta pergunta requer o uso de imagens para entender.

O R Markdown está desse jeito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso usar um *shortcut*, sem precisar clicar nas setas ao lado das *hashtags*, para fazer isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como fazer isso para um chunk específico e para todos de uma vez usando atalhos?

Estou usando o Linux. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já vou fazer uma ressalva inicialmente de que esta não é uma questão tão adequada ao stackoverflow. Era só procurar na documentação que você acharia. Mas enfim, seguem os atalhos:

**- Folding:**

```
 Collapse: Alt+L
 Expand: Shift+Alt+L
 Collapse All: Alt+O
 Expand All: Shift+Alt+O
```

**- Code:**

```
 Insert Section — Ctrl+Shift+R (Cmd+Shift+R on the Mac)
 Jump To — Shift+Alt+J
```

A seguir eu utilizando o <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> junto com <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]